# Change a specific input color text

Tags: html, css

I have two differents input and I'd like to specify different colors for each one.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <input type="file" name="img"/>
      <input type="submit" name="GO" value="FOI!"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

The *input file* has a button (color black) and a text(this is what I want to change the color).

The *input submit* is a button and I'd like to change the button's text color.

Is there a way to specify which input to apply a css effect?

Comment: is there a requirement to change the text color/appearance of the button in File field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input[type="file"]{     /* you can also use:   input[name="img"]   */
   color: fuchsia;
}

input[type="submit"]{
   color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="file" name="img"/>
    <input type="submit" name="GO" value="FOI!"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Some useful [resource link](http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/14636214755/making-file-inputs-a-pleasure-to-look-at) about additionally styling an `file` button</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Just make an id for the name of the input you want something like this.

```
<style>
#Go {
color: #DE2A00;
}
</style>
```